# Wpf scrollbar style triangle

Tags: wpf-controls

In [this](http://sachabarbs.wordpress.com/2008/01/11/styling-a-scrollviewerscrollbar-in-wpf/) article a scrollbar gets a new look. There is a line in the style which appears to put the triangle in the scroll buttons. I don't know how to read it though.

```
Content="M 0 0 L 4 4 L 8 0 Z"/>
```

What does that mean in the context of the control?

Comment: Think I've solved it. There's a Windows.Shapes.Path in there. I assume these are Logo like instructions to the path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just the geometry for the [Path Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.path.data.aspx). If you'd like to reproduce it just do something like `<Path Data="YourPath"/>`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah, I figured out the M meant move, L was Line and Z was end. I had completely missed the fact there was a Path object in there I thought it was a Path= property if you see what I mean :)